# Get unid of document before it is saved and have it not change when saved

Tags: xpages

I have an XPage that has a single data source `document1`. I would like to know the unid of the document before it has been saved.

It's seems this is possible because `document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()` returns a value before it is saved.

However, this value always changes once the document is saved then it remains constant. Is there a way to set the unid so it doesn't change when saved? I've tried `if (document1.isNewNote()) document1.getDocument().setUniversalID(document1.getDocument().getUniversalID())` but it is still changing when saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change document's id on dominoDocument's `querySaveDocument` event.

```css
if (document1.isNewNote()) {
    document1.getDocument().setUniversalID(yourID);
}
```

Here is a complete XPage example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument
            var="document1"
            formName="Test">
            <xp:this.querySaveDocument><![CDATA[#{javascript:
              if (document1.isNewNote()) {
                document1.getDocument().setUniversalID(document1.getItemValueString("id"));
              }
            }]]></xp:this.querySaveDocument>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:inputText
        value="#{document1.id}"
        defaultValue="#{javascript:document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()}">
    </xp:inputText>

    <xp:button
        value="Label"
        id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete"
            immediate="false"
            save="true">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```